# VBS Sync Center Synchronize offline files

Tags: vbscript, center, synchronization

I'm trying to sync offline files with a VBScript. I've edited the code below to sync three paths:

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
strUserName = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%USERNAME%" )

strPathProfile = "\\SRV01\Path1$\" & strUserName
strPathHome = "\\SRV01\Path2$\" & strUserName
strPathShared = "\\SRV01\Path3$"

    SynchronizeOfflineFiles strPathProfile
    SynchronizeOfflineFiles strPathShared
    SynchronizeOfflineFiles strPathHome

Sub SynchronizeOfflineFiles(strSyncPath)
Dim objShell
Dim objFolderPath
    Set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")
    Set objFolderPath = objShell.NameSpace(strSyncPath)

    If (not objFolderPath is nothing) then
        objFolderPath.Synchronize

    End If

    Set objFolderPath = nothing
    Set objShell = nothing
End Sub
```

My only problem is that sync center will sync the paths one by one, as result that two of them will fail. The path on top (in this case strPathProfile) will succeed. So if I change the order to for example:

```
SynchronizeOfflineFiles strPathHome
SynchronizeOfflineFiles strPathShared
SynchronizeOfflineFiles strPathProfile
```

strPathHome will succeed, and the other two will fail.

When I use the `WScript.Sleep 5000` command Like this:

```
SynchronizeOfflineFiles strPathProfile
WScript.Sleep 30000
SynchronizeOfflineFiles strPathShared
WScript.Sleep 30000
SynchronizeOfflineFiles strPathHome
```

It will wait for the other paths to sync, But i have to set an time. Is it possible to wait until the previous sync is completed?

I also receive the error: There is no script engine for file extension ".vbs" when one of the shares is offline. Can I let the script check whether the share is online and if not skip to the next?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you run sub SynchronizeOfflineFiles before the first one completes. Then, when it does, you have Set objFolderPath = nothing.

You can either run sub with different arguments after the previous one completes, or you can write multiple versions of SynchronizeOfflineFiles with a differentobjFolderPath.

Comment: The strange thing is that if I write multiple versions of SynchronizeOfflineFiles with a differentobjFolderPath, it will not sync the only path I asked. But if I put the three paths together like before it will sync one path. but the status of the other two paths is: Synchronization pending. and when the first path is synced they will fail. When I push the Sync All button in Sync Center it will sync all the paths at the same time without errors. Is this possible with a vbs script?